# R - How to make a function return nothing (not NULL, just avoid the value from being created)

Tags: r, null, return, try-catch, apply

I have a `tryCatch()` clause inside a `lapply()` loop that will either output a data.frame if the input value is valid, or `NULL` if it doesn't. Thus, the list resulting from that contains elements from both classes. Here an example:

```
a = list(1, 2, "skere", 3)
b = lapply(a, function(x){
  tryCatch({
    out = data.frame("number" = x,
                     "mod2" = x%%2) # This will fail for characters
    return(out)
  },
  error = function(e) {})
})
```

The result of `print(b)` would then be:

```
[[1]]
  number mod2
1     1    1

[[2]]
  number mod2
1     2    0

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
  number mod2
1     3    1
```

In my case, I want to collapse the list of dataframes into a single dataframe, and `dplyr::bind_rows()` fortunately omits the NULL from being appended. Therefore, it is not a huge problem now, but it could be a problem in some other case.

So the question is: Is there a way to completely omit the `NULL` from being returned in the first place?

Comment: Have the error function return a data.frame with zero rows instead of NULL. R functions must return something.

Comment: No exceptions? Do they **have** to return something always?

Comment: A function must have a function body. It's impossible to write a function body that doesn't return something (even { is a function and as you discovered it returns NULL if you don't pass it anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already know `dplyr::bind_rows(b)` will omit `NULL` values so you don't really need to do anything.

Another way is to just remove those `NULL` values which can be done using `Filter`.

```
Filter(length, b)

#[[1]]
#  number mod2
#1      1    1

#[[2]]
#  number mod2
#1      2    0

#[[3]]
#  number mod2
#1      3    1
```

Or

```
b[!sapply(b, is.null)]
```

Comment: My question was more about the possibility of a function not returning something, but Roland just clarified me that it's impossible. Still, thanks for the tricks to overcome it! I'll definitely write them down ^^

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `discard` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
discard(b, is.null)
#[[1]]
#  number mod2
#1      1    1

#[[2]]
#  number mod2
#1      2    0

#[[3]]
#  number mod2
#1      3    1
```